# How do I generate a url inside a c# service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Really simple I hope. I just want to do the equivalent of

```
Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { id = 3 });
```

But inside a service class. Not inside a controller class or IActionResult method

In a plain old service class. Because of the service call having all the data I don't want to pass in other information so my service call is nice and clean.

I've come close but nothing seems to work, either that or it cant be done.

I tried to dependency inject this

```
services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x => x
            .GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>()
            .GetUrlHelper(x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext));
```

In my service call I used (DI) this

```
public AdminService(..., IUrlHelper urlHelper)
```

so in my service method I could to this

```
string editUrl = _urlHelper.Action("EditRole", "Admin", new { id = 0 });
```

which got rid of all the red squiglies but at run time this bit caused me a problem

```
            .GetUrlHelper(x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext));
```

Comment: "I've come close but nothing seems to work," -- then show us the code you've written that "comes close" and maybe we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You can inject IUrlHelper interface inside a service class.

```
public class ServiceClass
    {
        private readonly IActionContextAccessor _actionContextAccessor;
        private readonly IUrlHelperFactory _urlHelperFactory;

        public ServiceClass(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor,
            IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory,)
        {
            _actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
            _urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory;
        }

        public string CreateUrl()
        {
            var urlHelper = _urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(_actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
            string url = urlHelper.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController");

            return url;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok that's closer but what do I ut in startup.cs to add those services. I'm getting `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`

Comment: you need add to ConfigureServices above codes.

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

Answer (score 0):

@SMM I had to add this to my startup but otherwise, works, so thank you

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IUrlHelper, UrlHelper>();
```

Answer (score -2):

Url.Action generates only an url.
@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { id = id })

Html.ActionLink generates an  tag automatically.

Comment: not gonna downvote you cos you tried at least to help. But that's not what I am trying to do but thanks anyway :)